# Remove duplicates in php drop down list

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a php drop down list which retrieves locations from a database, it gets all the data correctly, but sometimes if two records has the same in the database, it will add the item twice in the drop down. This is a location drop down, and some locations are duplicates, i would like to know what code can i add to remove duplicate entries and just keep one.

Here is my code:

```
               <label for="select-service">
                <strong>Enter a Location:</strong>
            </label>
            <select class="form-control" id="select-location" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-control" required>
                <option value="">Select Location</option>



                 <?php
            foreach($appointment_locations as $location) {

             $LocationsArray = explode(",", $location->notes);

              foreach($LocationsArray as $singleLocation):
                 ?>

                <option value="<?=$singleLocation ?>"><?=$singleLocation  ?></option>                  

                <? endforeach;

                 };?>

            </select>
```

EDIT:

Here is the output
[image]

I tried using `foreach(array_unique($appointment_locations) as $location) {` but it doesnt show my second provider when i click on the location `Rosebank`

Comment: try `array_unique()` it will remove duplicates.

Comment: @Akhilesh should i put `$singleLocation` in `array_unique()` ?

Comment: try to edit you question and add what you are getting in `$appointment_locations` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) validate your inserted data to avoid such a situations

2) why you do not `group by` your retrieved data from database?

---

if you do not have access to do this, you can try a simple solution rather than the `array_unique` solution

```
$tmp = [];
foreach ($repeatedLocations as $location) {
    if (isset($tmp[$location]) == false) {
        // do your stuff
        $tmp[$location] = true;
    }
}
unset($tmp);
```

Comment: would i add all my code under the place you commented `do your stuff`?

Comment: not literally , I just wanted to clarify it to you, adjust it to fit your case.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
foreach(array_unique($appointment_locations) as $location) {
//... code
```

or

```
$LocationsArray = array_unique(explode(",", $location->notes));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php